With Pyomo, How to Access Parameter by Index in Constraint Definition ? TypeError: '_generic_component_decorator' object is not subscriptable
I'm doing exercises to learn how to use pyomo. I've tried setting parameters on an index, as the doc does, but I get an error when I try to access the parameters in the constraints.
I understand from the documentation that the Param object behaves in much the same way as the Var object. I therefore expected to be able to access parameter values in the same way as I access variable values in the constraint definition.
Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Here the code :
import pyomo.environ as pyo
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory

#Model
model = pyo.ConcreteModel()

#Set
model.index_1 = pyo.RangeSet(1,2)
model.index_2 = pyo.RangeSet(0,2)

#Variables
model.pg = pyo.Var(model.index_1)
model.pg[1].setlb(0)
model.pg[2].setlb(0)
model.pg[1].setub(20)
model.pg[2].setub(30)
model.c = pyo.Var(model.index_1, bounds=(0, None))
model.m = pyo.Var(model.index_2, bounds=(-15, 15))
model.b = pyo.Var(model.index_2, bounds=(None, None))

#Parameters
model.Cg = model.Param(model.index_1, initialize={1: 0.2, 2: 0.5})
model.Pl = model.Param(model.index_2, initialize={0: 15, 1: 15, 2: 15})
model.Pd = model.Param(initialize=25)

#Objective
model.obj = pyo.Objective(expr = pyo.summation(model.c), sense=pyo.minimize)

#Constraints
model.C1 = pyo.ConstraintList()
for i in model.index_1:
    model.C1.add(expr = model.pg[i] * model.Cg[i] == model.c[i])
model.C2 = pyo.ConstraintList()
model.C2.add(expr = model.b[0] == model.m[0]*model.Pl[0] + model.m[1]*model.Pl[1])
model.C2.add(expr = model.b[1] == model.m[0]*model.Pl[0] + model.m[2]*model.Pl[2])
model.C2.add(expr = model.b[2] == model.m[1]*model.Pl[1] + model.m[2]*model.Pl[2])
model.C3 = pyo.Constraint(expr = model.b[2] == model.Pd)
model.C4 = pyo.ConstraintList()
model.C4.add(expr = model.b[0] >= -model.Pg[1])
model.C4.add(expr = model.b[1] >= -model.Pg[2])

opt = SolverFactory('glpk')
opt.solve(model)

print('--------------------------------------------------------------------')
for i in model.index_1:
    print(f"pg[{i}]: {pyo.value(model.pg[i])}")
for i in model.index_1:
    print(f"c[{i}]: {pyo.value(model.c[i])}")
for j in model.index_2:
    print(f"m[{j}]: {pyo.value(model.m[j])}")
for j in model.index_2:
    print(f"b[{j}]: {pyo.value(model.b[j])}")

print("Total cost: ", pyo.summation(model.c))

Here the exception :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exercice9.py", line 26, in <module>
    model.C1.add(expr = model.pg[i] * model.Cg[i] == model.c[i])
                                      ~~~~~~~~^^^
TypeError: '_generic_component_decorator' object is not subscriptable

I've tried to define the constraints in different ways, in particular by using rules, but it doesn't change anything.
def rule_1(model, i):
    return model.pg[i] * model.Cg[i] == model.c[i]
model.C1 = pyo.Constraint(model.index_1, rule=rule_1)


Your syntax where you make the params is incorrect.  Instead of this:
model.Cg = model.Param(model.index_1, initialize={1: 0.2, 2: 0.5})

Do this:
model.Cg = pyo.Param(model.index_1, initialize={1: 0.2, 2: 0.5})

